# Is there any httpresponse header that would redirect user to some page of my site?

Tags: http, httprequest, httpresponse

I am a server. User sends http requests to me. I wonder if there is some http response header that would tall user web browser to auto rederect to some `/my/server/page.html`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`Location`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) header with a response code in the [3xx-range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_status_code#3xx_Redirection).

For an example:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /my/server/page.html
```

Answer (score 2):

`301` and `302` HTTP codes can be used to redirect requests, like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved
Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2011 10:37:34 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Location: http://www.xyz.com/abc
```